# VM Monitoring Tool

Tags: virtual-machine, monitoring

I Have 70 VM machine ( Windows, RHEL, Solaris). 
Can anyone suggest me any tool that can help me monitor all of them at ta single UI.

Details I can provide:

- IP of the VM.
- Login Details.

Details that should be provided by the VM Monitoring tool.

1. Instance is up or no
2. Number of Disk Drives.
3. Spaces available in each drive.
4. Any other details will also be helpful.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ITRS Geneos](http://www.itrsgroup.com/product/geneos-overview). It has lots of plug-ins available and work for both Windows/Unix systems. Also can be customized as per requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Zabbix does a great job, and is open source

Answer (score -1):

You can try numerous open source monitoring tools like nagios, zabbix, cacti, Icinga . Zabbix is quite good as it is new in the market.